# Authentication using Django’s sessions db from Apache

Tags: django, apache, authentication, mod-wsgi

I have a Django application which I now want to integrate it with Kibana. So when authenticated users click on a link, they will be directed to Kibana. But this option should not be available to anonymous users.

My stack is Psql + Django + mod_wsgi + Apache. The solution I came up with was restricting access to Kibana via Apache, and authenticating users in Django before giving them access. [This HowTo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/) in Django website says how you can authenticate against Django from Apache, but that one uses Basic authentication. When I use this approach, even for users who already have an active session in my Django app, they will be asked to enter their username/password in a browser dialog!

I was hoping the authentication to happen using the current Django active sessions. I believe for that I need to use `AuthType form` and `mod_session`, instead of `AuthType Basic`, but it seems `mod_wsgi` does not support `mod_session` yet (as [discussed here](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/pull/41)). I checked other WSGI alternatives as well (`gunicorn` and `uWSGI`), but couldn't find anything.

So my question is how I can Authenticate against Django session db? Is using `mod_session` + `AuthType form` correct? and if yes, what's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It isn't that mod_wsgi has no plans to add mod_session support, it is just a lot of work and no personal free time to do it. Has been on the TODO list for a long time. Anyway, this topic is way too complicated for StackOverflow. Use the mod_wsgi mailing list to discuss it. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/finding-help.html

Comment: Thanks, @GrahamDumpleton. You are right, you had mentioned the plan to support `mod_session`. I updated my question to reflect this. I will follow up on the mailing list.